# I have been having

Tags: tense

I would like to inquire about "I have been having". My understanding is that this composition is a perfect-present-continuous tense, but what it exactly really means in the following sentences:

```
I have been having trouble sharing my neighbors wireless connection.
I have been having trouble sharing my house.
```

Is there such a tense? I understood from the previous examples that "I have been" is present perfect tense, and when we add "having" it tells us that the issue is still continue until the moment of the speech and may be further in future.

When we should use "i have been having ..." or what is (are) the motivation(S)for using it in a sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Have been having" isn't a single phrase, it's part of "have been having trouble", which contains two parts and two different meanings of "have".

In the first half, "have been" expresses action that started in the past and continues to the present.

In the second half, "Having" means experiencing, i.e., experiencing trouble.

> I **am** having trouble sharing my neighbors wireless connection.

means I am currently experiencing trouble sharing my neighbors wireless connection.

> I **have been** having trouble sharing my neighbors wireless connection.

means that trouble sharing my neighbors wireless connection is an ongoing situation that I started to experience in the past and am still experiencing now.